# AWS Cloudwatch does not log Lambda stacktraces

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a NodeJS Lambda deployed in AWS. Works fine but whenever errors happen, the entire and details of the error is not shown in AWS Cloudwatch. CW shows all console.info output but does not show the stack trace of the exception. If we run the Lambda in our local machines, the console logs would look like the one below:

```
****START METHOD EXECUTION****
****END METHOD EXECUTION******


/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/dbutility.js:45
  await connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', record, async function (error, results, fields) {
                             ^
  at Handshake.onConnect (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:58:9)
  at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
  at Handshake._callback (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
  at Sequence.end (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
  at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:369:14)
  at Connection._handleNetworkError (/Users/john.doe/Documents/workspace/myproject/user-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
  at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
  at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
```

But when the same Lambda is deployed in AWS, the Cloudwatch logs we see is only the one below

```
****START METHOD EXECUTION****
****END METHOD EXECUTION******
```

In our codes, we catch error using the usual try catch:

```
try {
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

How can we display error stack trace or details in the CW logs?

Comment: Does your Lambda function has permission to put log to cloudwatch logs?

Comment: yes it has permission

Comment: Can you try to deploy another Lambda with the same setting, and the only code is one try catch block with exception to see if it write logs to cloudwatch?
This looks like your code are not executing catch block or something. Not Nodejs problem.